# MYSQL: count if value from one table exists in multiple columns in another table

Tags: mysql, left-join, multiple-columns

wondering if anyone one can assist,

I have a fixed reference table

tblConfig_qC

```
----------------
| id | value   |
----------------
| 1  | optionA |
| 2  | optionB |
| 3  | optionC |
| 4  | optionD |
| 5  | optionE |
| 6  | optionF |
| 7  | optionG |
----------------
```

And a tblSubmission table where I have 3 columns which stores which of the option users selected (from the tblConfig_qC table)

User can select between 1 to 3 options

So typically, rows can be like:

tblSubmissions

```
------------------------------------
| id | qC1     | qC2     | qC3     |
------------------------------------
| 1  | optionB |         |         |
| 2  | optionA | optionD | optionE |
| 3  | optionC | optionD | optionF |
| 4  | optionD | optionF |         |
------------------------------------
```

What i need to do is create a summary of counts:

```
-------------------------
| id | Options | Counts |
-------------------------
| 1  | optionA | 0      |
| 2  | optionB | 1      |
| 3  | optionC | 1      |
| 4  | optionD | 3      |
| 5  | optionE | 1      |
| 6  | optionF | 2      |
| 7  | optionG | 0      |
-------------------------
```

I can do this for one column but how do i add the counts of the other 2?

```
SELECT q.value AS 'Option',  
COUNT(s.qC1) AS 'qC1',
FROM tblConfig_qC q 
LEFT JOIN tblSubmission s ON q.value = s.qC1
group by q.value ORDER BY q.value;
```

Comment: Normalising `tblSubmissions` as `(submit_id, option_id)` with a composite `UNIQUE KEY` of both those fields could simplify a lot of things, including the aggregation logic. (What if there was a need for you to accept upto 4 options instead of 3 in future?)

Comment: Thanks, i think you're right. 
But for now, I've addd an OR statement to get thisworking:

`LEFT JOIN tblSubmission s ON ( (q.value = s.qC1) OR (q.value = s.qC2) OR (q.value = s.qC3) )`

May be a little bit of a hack...